# Grunt how to get files outside main folder

Tags: gruntjs

I am using grunt connect server for maven angular project. I have some static files outside the angular  folder. Is there way to redirect every call for file "redirect_folder/x/y/file.txt" to "target_folder/x/y/file.txt" just grunt need to change redirect_folder word for my static folder path.

Edit:

I copied the user.json to style folder, and trying to make style folder as a base but it doesnt works:

```
$http.get('user.json')
```

grunt.js:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    connect: {
        all: {
            options: {
                base: ['/media/data/project/src/main/webapp/resources/ngSrc/app'],
                port: 10100,
                hostname: "0.0.0.0",
                livereload: true,
                combine : [ '/media/data/project/src/main/webapp/resources/ngSrc/app', '/media/data/project/src/main/webapp/resources/ngSrc/app/style']
            }
        }
    },
...
```

Comment: It's `grunt-connect` you are using right ? If it's, have you tried the combine option in the settings ?

Comment: I have tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-connect-rewrite but the problem is that the target directory is outside main folder of gruntfile

Comment: Okay. Why are you keeping those static files outside the base ? Why not move the target_folder inside the base directory of the server ?

Comment: cause those files are generated by another project and files shouldn't be modified. They are added to few projects as dependency, and unpacked with maven to target folder.

Comment: Okay, then will it be okay to serve the files from that directory directly ? I mean why use a redirect ?

Comment: For the begining it would be ok. I ve tried it already I just unpacked it to some folder in project and it worked. But when files are outside app folder I cannot reach them with ~"./././././target". Why redirect - because it looks quite unprofessional this path "././././.target"

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. If you are okay with not redirecting, you can use the `combine` setting in grunt-connect to have an additional base that can point to anywhere in the file system. In your case you can use the setting like `combine : [ <main root>, '../target_folder']` and after that the files in the target folder will be served directly -- if it isn't found at the first base.

Comment: But still you wont have URLs like `/target_folder/x/y/file.txt`, instead you will have URLs like `/x/y/file.txt` that are served from the target folder.

Comment: I ve edited first post. I am trying to use what u said but it not working and i dont get any error ...